# Ubuntu 16.10 - No headphone output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones, 16.10

**Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, Dell Latitude 3540**

With 16.10, when you insert the **headphone** jack, it senses and a dialog comes up, to which I selected "Headphones", but **no sound** comes.

**Sound is fine on speakers. Sound is fine on headphones under windows.**

I tried alsamixer, and it correctly shows headphones at 00,100, and speakers at MM.

pavucontrol shows sound coming from VLC player and headphone output at 100%

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Before I start meddling with conf files in alsa-mixer, does anyone have a clue on what could be going wrong? Everything was fine in 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run this on the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add the following:

```
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-dock
```

Unplug and plug your headphones and restart if necessary. 
I hope that helps. Good luck!